# why are the elements in array being stored as an integer, instead of the actual value in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a chat website. In the chat website, you may direct message any user as long as you know their username. Once you type in the username, it creates a new document in the "Groups" database. Here is the schema:

`users: Array`

`dmId: String`

`dmSecret: String`

`messages: Array`

I know I probably could've made the secure thing a lot easier, but that's not them. For some reason, when I am adding the group chat ID to an array inside a user document, it just comes out as

[image]

Thats weird, it was supposed to equal

`["whatever group id"]`

not

`[2]`

Here is how I am storing this (mongoose)

(Friend is the user document, and "newDmID" is the correct value, not 1 or 2, also I only use this if there is not already an array there`

`friend[0].dms = new Array().push(newDmID)`

I have bad english, sorry if I am not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node.js this is not a proper way to initiate an array. Use:

```
friend[0].dms = [newDmID]
```

OR:

```
friend[0].dms = new Array(newDmID)
```

This is not a mongoDB issue

Comment: Two things, one I tried the top thing already, didn't work, and two, if I console.dir the output of `[newDmID]` it shows what I want it to show.

Thanks though!

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as the solution, because this helped me look for more problems, and I ended up fixing mine! I had to change much of my code, but it is nothing related to this question so.